# How to Replace All Occurrences of Carriage Return Using Ant 

Tags: regex, ant

I am trying to replace all occurrences of a carriage return (`"\x0D"`) using a simple ant task, all `*.sh` files in the test directory. It does not seem to do the trick.

This is my script; am I doing something wrong? (It seems the global flag, `g`, does not help either)

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<project name="myproject" default="cr_remover" basedir=".">
  <target name="cr_remover">
    <replaceregexp match="\x0D" replace="" flags="g" byline="true">
      <fileset dir="."><include name="**/*.sh"/></fileset> 
    </replaceregexp>
  </target>
</project>
```

Comment: thank you guys for the answers and the feedback! both helped ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will work:

```
<replaceregexp match="\x0D" replace="" flags="sg">
```

May I ask why you are not using [FixCRLF task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fixcrlf.html)?

```
<fixcrlf srcdir="." includes="**/*.sh"
  eol="lf"
  eof="remove"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the apache replaceregexp man page

```
<replaceregexp match="\s+" replace=" " flags="g" byline="true">
    <fileset dir="${html.dir}" includes="**/*.html"/>
</replaceregexp>
```

Note that you have

```
 <fileset dir="."><include name="**/*.sh"/></fileset>
```

I'm not enough of an ant person to know if that is what is causing your problem.